# Proof of this inequality

Tags: calculus, analysis

How can I prove that $$\left(\sqrt{|x|}-\sqrt{|y|}\right)^2\leq |x-y|.$$ Simplifying the right hand side doesn't seem to be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:**

$LHS \leq \left(\sqrt{||x| - |y||}\right)^2 \leq ||x| - |y|| \leq |x - y| = RHS$

**Method 2:** Let $|x| = a \geq 0$, and $|y| = b \geq 0$, and assume WLOG that: $a \geq b$: then:

$LHS = \left(\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}\right)^2$.

Using the triangle inequality we have:

$RHS \geq ||x| - |y|| = |a - b| = \left(\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}\right)(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b})$.

Thus: $LHS \leq RHS \iff \sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b} \leq \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} \iff 0 \leq 2\sqrt{b}$, and this is clearly true.

Comment: Why is $LHS \leq (\sqrt{||x|-|y||})^2$ ?